# ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in wamp from public ip in "My system"

Tags: php, wamp

I can access my wamp server via localhost in my system (port :8080), but not with public ip.

But then again when i try to access my wamp from other networks via public ip, yes i can get in.

The error i receive is "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED" it says that connect is rejected.

I have configured everything correctly, yes i have the apache config file set to allow all.

any clue?

Comment: Apache may be set up correctly, it's your machine/network hardware that isn't allowing incoming connections.  You need to allow the port through your firewall to the outside world.  Then you'll probably need to forward the port through your router (since you're probably behind a NAT).

Comment: how do you think others can access my wamp... and also for your info my firewall and antivirus is of... it's kind of a weird situation...

Comment: What do you mean by "how"?  What is the problem here?  I assumed you were trying to access your WAMP-hosted page from outside your network.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Please read the Question carefully... i meant i can't access my wamp server with my public ip within the network the server is hosted... but when i tried to access my wamp from any other network like mobile data or other wifi i can get inside my wamp server... is clear enough or do you want me pictograph it for you? and please don't take things in hard way... i am just tired of finding what's happening in my system...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this. [LINK](http://help.screenconnect.com/Cannot_access_external_IP_address_from_LAN)

It could be NAT loopback that causes this for you